# Why My py2app is not working , launch error

Tags: python

I built my app , :

```
import os, shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
#Ca ouvre le fichier et prend la derniere et avant derniere ligne
with open('Secrets.txt', 'r') as f:
    last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
#Ca fait la fenetre
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Rentre un secret")
window.geometry('1100x60')
#Ton secret
lbl = Label(window, text="Ton secret:")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt = Entry(window,width=100)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
txt.pack
#ecrire dans le fichier txt ton secret
def enreg():
    "Enregistrer ton secret"
    obfichier = open('Secrets.txt','a')
    if txt.get():
        obfichier.write(txt.get()+"\n")
    obfichier.close()
    
bou2 = Button(window, text = 'Enregistrer', command = enreg)
bou2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
#L'autre Secret
log = Label(window, text="L'ancien secret: " + last_line)
log.grid(column=1, row=1)
directorya = txt.get()
```

but when I do
./dist/TonSecret.app/Contents/MacOS/TonSecret
,
it does nothing..
and when I click on the app icon it tells me :
Launch error
Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
can u help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A minor nit-pick...please don't supply code that won't work because of a missing input file that you don't provide.  It seems that the contents of the `Secrets.txt` file isn't important to the question.  I would suggest that if you are in a similar situation in the future, you replace the code that reads the file with code that simply sets `last_line` to a string constant.

Answer (score 1):

`py2app` issues aside, this code doesn't do anything because you're never entering the `tkinter` event loop.  Add this line to the end of your code and your code will do something:

```
window.mainloop()
```

If you want help in understanding why what you get when applying `py2app` doesn't work, you'll need to provide more information about just what you're doing to build your executable.

Comment: thanks , I do code since 2pm so I don't know everything